# RTMFP RTMP too slow on deployment

Tags: rtmp, flash-media-server, rtmfp

We have developed a 1-1 video conferencing solution using RTMP , RTMFP technologies using Adobe. We are making use of Flash Media Development Server for recording the web streams. We have tested our application locally and it seems to work good.

Thus, We deployed the application to our server but the latency is very high (like 15 seconds). I mean when i talk , the other party gets my voice after 15 - 20 seconds.

Could someone explain me what is the real problem behind this ?
Do i have to purchase this https://secure1.influxis.com/webrootv10/custom_enterprise/index.aspx

**Application.xml**
http://www.2shared.com/document/PfMTpQsJ/Application.html

Thanks.

Comment: Influxis uses Flash Media Server like the rest of us, don't pay them money unless they can guarantee an improvement. We used plain vanilla FMS and did not have the latency issue you describe. For live, realtime communications you should use RTMFP. RTMP has inherent latency in that it will attempt to play all video frames rather than dropping them when it lags due to network, etc.

Comment: Finally there are many parameters that can affect latency: the resolution/quality of the video being the most notable.

Comment: @SunilD. , Thanks for the reply. This is the Application.xml (linked it on the question) we are currently using for our application. Are all these correct ?